# trouble getting flot tooltip to appear

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to get a flot tooltip to appear, but nothing is happening. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please? Maybe it doesn't recognize my points, they are appearing on the graph (number of people on y axis, the years on the x-axis).

```
$.post('php/myprogram.php', 
                 function(output){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( output );
                        var data = [];
                        var coordinate = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i< obj.length-1; i++) {
                            coordinate.push(obj[i][0]);
                            coordinate.push(obj[i][1]);
                            data.push(coordinate);
                            coordinate = [];
                        }

                            var options = {
                                xaxis: {
                                    axisLabel: 'YEAR',
                                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 15,
                                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial',
                                    tickDecimals: 0
                                },
                                yaxis: {
                                    axisLabel: '',
                                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 15,
                                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial'
                                },
                                series: {
                                    lines: {
                                        show: true,
                                        color: '#ffa500'
                                    },
                                    points: {
                                        show: true
                                    }
                                },
                                grid: {
                                    hoverable: true
                                }
                            };

                            $.plot($("#byYear"),
                                    [data],
                                   options
                            );


                        function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
                            $("<div id='tooltip'>" + contents + "</div>").css({
                                position: "absolute",
                                display: "none",
                                top: y + 5,
                                left: x + 5,
                                border: "1px solid #fdd",
                                padding: "2px",
                                "background-color": "#fff",
                                opacity: 0.80
                            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);

                        }


                        $("#byYear").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                                var str = "(" + pos.x.toFixed(2) + ", " + pos.y.toFixed(2) + ")";
                                //$("#hoverdata").text(str);

                                if (item) {
                                    if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {

                                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2);
                                        var y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                                        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, str);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                                    previousPoint = null;            
                                }

                        }); //end bind
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raidri was partly right - my tooltip needed to be outside my code. But I had to do a different way:

html: (I included just the basic flot code)

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
<div id="byYear"></div>
```

css:

```
#byYear {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.80;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

jquery:

```
$.post('php/myprogram.php', 
                 function(output){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( output );
                        var data = [];
                        var coordinate = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i< obj.length-1; i++) {
                            coordinate.push(obj[i][0]);
                            coordinate.push(obj[i][1]);
                            data.push(coordinate);
                            coordinate = [];
                        }

                            var options = {
                                xaxis: {
                                    axisLabel: 'YEAR',
                                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 15,
                                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial',
                                    tickDecimals: 0
                                },
                                yaxis: {
                                    axisLabel: '',
                                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 15,
                                    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial'
                                },
                                series: {
                                    lines: {
                                        show: true,
                                        color: '#ffa500'
                                    },
                                    points: {
                                        show: true
                                    }
                                },
                                grid: {
                                    hoverable: true
                                }
                            };

                            $("#byYear").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                                if (item) {
                                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(0),
                                            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);

                                        $("#tooltip").html(y + " instances")
                                            .css({top: item.pageY+5, left: item.pageX+5})
                                            .fadeIn(200);
                                    } else {
                                        $("#tooltip").hide();
                                    }

                            });
                            $.plot($("#byYear"),
                                    [data],
                                   options
                            );



                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wb9pptew/).

But you define the `showTooltip()` and `bind()` functions inside the `$.post()` callback. This means that after multiple ajax calls you call the `plothover` function multiple times. Try moving the two functions out of the `$.post()` callback.

Comment: Nothing changes if I move the two functions out of the $.post() callback. Seems like something's amiss with the way I'm writing the code.

Comment: Could you try to build a version of your page as fiddle which shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "[flot.tooltip](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip)" plugin instead of handling the `plothover` events on your own.